# Can only the right drawable folder be used when installing an application?

Tags: java, android, image, size, drawable

I would like to know if it's posssible to load only the right drawable folder. Example, if a user have a xhdpi screen, I don't want that the user download the folder xxhpi in his application, because it's useless and it will only consume space.

I heard that Android does this by itself, but when I tested the application still was still downloading all images.

UPDATE: the only possibility that I saw is to create more than one apk, but I don't know, if this solution is the best or not.

Comment: What do you mean by "loading" and "downloading"? Do you mean the action that happens when the application is installed, or when the application is started?

Comment: when the application is installed